# Protractor debug error - no such file or directory, acces "d:\project_root\node_modules\protractor\bin\package.json

Tags: debugging, jasmine, protractor, package.json

I am trying to debug the protractor tests with jasmine framework in VS Code and getting error:

```
Exception has occurred: Error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'd:\project_root\node_modules\protractor\bin\package.json'
    at Object.accessSync (fs.js:229:3)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (d:\project_root\node_modules\path-exists\index.js:12:6)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (d:\project_root\node_modules\locate-path\index.js:20:18)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (d:\project_root\node_modules\find-up\index.js:34:27)
```

**launch.json** file is as below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program", 
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\protractor\\bin\\protractor",
            "args":["${workspaceRoot}\\test-suites\\protractor\\conf.js"],
        }
    ]
}
```

my package.json file is present in the project_root directory, however I want to use the protractor as a program which is in another directory, and it looks like it tries to search for the package.json in the --bin\protractor directory.

PLEASE NOTE:
I am able to execute the tests in cmd or terminal correctly without any error using below command, but I want to go in the debug mode in VS code which doesn't work:
`protractor test-suites\\protractor\\conf.js`
which executes all the tests in conf.js

---

I have tried:
program as conf.js file in the launch.json, which starts the debugging but didn't execute any test, may be node didn't understand the tests to be executed in the conf.js file

webdriver-manager update in both node_modules/.bin

Specify path of a package.json file in the args section in the launch.json like

```
npm --prefix ${workspaceRoot} run
```

relative/absolute path for package.json - nothing worked, fails with the same exception mentioned above

versions:

node --version
v14.17.0

npm --version
6.14.13

protractor --version
7.0.0

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this file exist when you go check, d:\project_root\node_modules\protractor\bin\package.json? I think this could be the issue. You could try doing a fresh npm install.

Comment: hi @AliF50
thank you for your comment. As per my understanding package.json file needs to be present at root directory. I tried npm install at root directory but that didn't create package.json file in the protractor\bin directory. So the issue persists. However, when I run the tests it through cmd using protractor command it works perfect. Unable to get what is issue with debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.